# Generate periodically structured holes in non-linear mesh (make curved fence)

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to make a fence on a curved bridge.

Currently a have a bridge mesh and a fence mesh, that repeats bridge curvature, but is solid. I need to make holes in that mesh as shown in the picture below.

Obviously, I can manually create meshes, put them to the mesh and make hole by boolean modifier, but the bridge is pretty long, so, perhaps, there is an opportunity to automize this procces?

[image]

---

It's actually resembles me numerical solution for calculating definitive integral, that I was programming on C in university, so, in case if this is kinda unregular task, maybe, somehow using python I can make that?

Or maybe there are another, more easier and correct methods to do that fence?

---

**Update 1**

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXBF4o6PO8c) I explored an array modifier. It would be just super cool if instead of constant factor value it could be possible to set, for example sine function. But hover, now I am able two create *flat* fence.

Currently thinking how to bend it.

Comment: In the same base as the video you can use shrinkwrap (with vertex group) to adjust automatically the holes (+ boolean) or fence parts.

Comment: to bend look up some youtube on how to bend an array over a spline

Comment: @lemon tried, but every generated meshes (technically currently it is a single mesh) is rotating to constantly increasing angle for some reason

Comment: @Peter, yeah I learned how to bend with curve modifier, but, unfortunately I already deleted curve I used to bend bridge. I will try to remade it

Comment: I think providing more concrete information (.blend) about how you bridge is will help someone here to propose a solution for you.

Comment: @lemon, let make a few tries by myself, and then I will provide

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This GN group will project a mesh's X axis on to a given curve, while maintaining the original Y and Z offsets, in the original object-space. Unlike the *Curve* modifier, it does not map the off-axis dimensions to the curve's `Normal` and `Normal x Tangent`. It leaves them oriented along the original object axes:

[image]

It's often the case that if you set 'Fit Curve' as the count of an *Array* modifier, the result is slightly out.. the length of the curve is not an exact multiple of the element length. The green nodes in this group take the liberty of stretching the mesh slightly, so it fits the curve exactly.

In this example, the bridge is a straight *Array* of elements along X. Each element is the result of a *Mirror* in X and Y. This GN Group is then a helper: it does not generate the mesh. If you prefer using *Boolean* s, it could be an array of cutters.

[image]

It may not be perfect for you .. while the deformed railing has a constant Z thickness, it does not have a constant radial thickness.

[image]
(Blender 3.0)

Comment: I like this solution the most because it keeps all the railing supports vertical, which is something I was wondering about when I saw the question.

Comment: I will try to understand and recreate this method today, thanks

Comment: @АртурКлочко It may be useful to download the .blend to see the context the group is being used in.

Comment: For sure, I meant I will just do it soon today

Answer (score 5):

First add a path that will form the arc of the bridge and be the base curve for the [*curve modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html#curve-modifier) we will be using. <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *>curve>path* Also add a plane <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *mesh>plane* that is the length of the side of the bridge. This will be the fence object.

The curve and plane must have the same origin, so it will be easiest to keep the 3d cursor in one place, and set origins to the 3d cursor for the path and plane using *object>set origin>origin to 3d cursor*.

Add a *curve modifier* to the plane and select the path, set the axis accordingly and rotate if needed and apply transforms.
[image]

You should have something like this result:
[image]

Now add a cube, scaled to the size of the hole. Also add a *curve modifier*, then an [*array modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html#array-modifier) as pictured below.

[image]

Finally, a solidify and [*boolean modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#boolean-modifier) on the plane, setting the cube as the boolean object like so:

[image]

Here you will have something like this:
[image]

For the bridge itself, it would just be a matter of adding a grid object, and another *curve modifier* using the same path and setting origins to 3d cursor and following with a [*solidify modifier*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) for the following result:

[image]

Because this is all modifiers, it can all be adjusted or changed dynamically.

Here is the file to inspect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, probably accept Yours

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for not literally making holes, but can be considered as it. However, this is what I need. The main benefit of this method is that it does not requires adding any curves.

1. Create a vertically-stretched cube (or cylinder, or another stuff), and then go to `Modifiers` -> `Add modifier` -> `Array` and set offset and count you need.

[image]

2. Add 2 loop-cuted a lot times cubes as top and bottom "railings"

[image]

3. Combine these three meshes (vertical blocks are actually one modified mesh) using boolean modifier. Select one choose another as an object select "difference" and apply. Repeat again to create one monolith mesh (I recommend to use boolean addon and just `ctrl` + `shift` + `+` them)

[image]

4. Enable proportional editing by pressing `O` or click that button

[image]

5. Go to edit mode (`tab`) and choose these faces from both sides

[image]

6. Move them down. Notice `Move` toolbar appeared at the bottom-left corner of viewport

[image]

7. Open `Move` toolbar, and set `Proportional Size` to the value you need

[image]

8. Done
9. Now the easiest step waiting for you - texturing